# Can attributes be assigned anywhere within a class?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Can attributes be assigned anywhere within a class? If so, how do scope rules works for each of the following cases?

```
class GreatComposers(object):
    def __init__(self, name, birthday, instrument):

        # attributes assigned in __init__
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.instrument = instrument

    def setFullName(self)

        # attributes assigned in other class methods
        self.fullname = self.name + self.birthday
        self.job = self.instrument + 'ist'


    # attributes assigned outside any functions
    self.nationality = 'german'
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work at class scope (`self.nationality = 'german'` in your example), as there is no name `self` in scope at this point. And it doesn't work in the other cases because methods or the `self` parameter are somehow special. Attributes can be assigned *anywhere you have a reference to the object*. That includes methods, but also all other code that has access to the object in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and see:

**composers.py**

```
class GreatComposers(object):
    def __init__(self, name, birthday, instrument):

        # attributes assigned in __init__
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.instrument = instrument

    def setFullName(self):  # <<< added missing colon

        # attributes assigned in other class methods
        self.fullname = self.name + self.birthday
        self.job = self.instrument + 'ist'


    # attributes assigned outside any functions
    self.nationality = 'german'
```

```
>>> import composers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "composers.py", line 1, in <module>
    class GreatComposers(object):
  File "composers.py", line 17, in GreatComposers
    self.nationality = 'german'
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The traceback tells you that, outside a method, you can't assign anything to `self.nationality` because `self` doesn't exist (remember that `self` is just an argument like any other; it's not like `this` in javascript).

Inside a method, you can do what you like, and [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) **doesn't** warn against defining instance variables outside `__init__()`, but your code will be easier to follow if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

assigning self attributes outside of **init** goes against PEP 8, but you can still do it. self.nationality shouldn't work though because self isn't defined. Even if you found a work around it, I wouldn't recommend doing that.

**edit:** My mistake. I was confusing a pylint warning with pep 8 style. But still, don't do it.